# adding a label in geom_line in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I have two very similar plots, which have two y-axis - a bar plot and a line plot:

[image]

code:

```
sec_plot <- ggplot(data, aes_string (x = year, group = 1)) +
    geom_col(aes_string(y = frequency), fill = "orange", alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_line(aes(y = severity))
```

However, there are no labels. I want to get a label for the barplot as well as a label for the line plot, something like:

[image]

How can I add the labels to the plot, if there is only pone single group? is there a way to specify this manually? Until know I have only found option where the labels can be added by specifying them in the `aes`

EXTENSION (added a posterior):

```
getSecPlot <- function(data, xvar, yvar, yvarsec, groupvar){

  if ("agegroup" %in% xvar) xvar <- get("agegroup")
  # data <- data[, startYear:= as.numeric(startYear)]

  data <- data[!claims == 0][, ':=' (scaled = get(yvarsec) * max(get(yvar))/max(get(yvarsec)),
                                     param  = max(get(yvar))/max(get(yvarsec)))]

  param <- data[1, param] # important, otherwise not found in ggplot

  sec_plot <- ggplot(data, aes_string (x = xvar, group = groupvar)) +
    geom_col(aes_string(y = yvar, fill = groupvar, alpha = 0.5), position = "dodge") +
    geom_line(aes(y = scaled,  color = gender)) +
    scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./(param), name = paste0("average ", yvarsec),labels = function(x) format(x, big.mark = " ", scientific = FALSE))) +
    labs(y = paste0("total ", yvar)) +
    scale_alpha(guide = 'none') + 
    theme_pubclean() +
    theme(legend.title=element_blank(), legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white"))
}

plot.ExposureYearly <- getSecPlot(freqSevDataAge, xvar = "agegroup", yvar = "exposure", yvarsec = "frequency", groupvar = "gender")
plot.ExposureYearly
```

**How can the same be done on a plot where both the line plot as well as the bar plot are separated by gender?**

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of your dataset ? and the complete code you have use for getting the plot ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible solution.  The method I used was to move the color and fill inside the aes and then use scale_*_identity to create and format the legends.
Also, I needed to add a scaling factor for severity axis since ggplot does not handle the secondary axis well.

```
data<-data.frame(year= 2000:2005, frequency=3:8, severity=as.integer(runif(6, 4000, 8000)))

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

sec_plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = year)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = frequency, fill = "orange"), alpha = 0.6) +
  geom_line(aes(y = severity/1000, color = "black")) +
  scale_fill_identity(guide = "legend", label="Claim frequency (Number of paid claims per 100 Insured exposure)", name=NULL) +
  scale_color_identity(guide = "legend", label="Claim Severity (Average insurance payment per claim)", name=NULL) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis =sec_axis( ~ . *1, labels = label_dollar(scale=1000), name="Severity") ) +  #formats the 2nd axis
  guides(fill = guide_legend(order = 1),  color = guide_legend(order = 2))                                #control which scale plots first

sec_plot
```

[image]

Comment: To solve the problem of using `aes_string()` Try encasing the colors (orange & black) in the `enquote()` function

Comment: shQuote("orange") worked ... I was wondering if an extension of this was possible for, where both the barplot and line plot are separated by gender?

Comment: You could try the "group" aesthetic to gender to see if that works.

Comment: i trieed that (see the post edit), however i get an error `Error: Unknown colour name: M``?

Comment: If the aes is setting 'color=gender' then you will need to remove `scale_color_identity`.  scale_*_identity is excepting a vector of colors and not M&Fs.

Comment: I ended up using `scale_color_manual(guide='legend', values= alpha(c("M"="turquoise3", "F"="indianred2"),1), label=c('F', 'M'))`... however, i was surprised that the order for M anf F seemed to be reversed for `values`and `lebel`, therefore questioning if i did this right?